# How do I reuse a UIView for drawing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I'm implementing a horizontal carousel of items - a bit like a UITableView, but with the cells arranged horizontally rather than vertically.  I'd like it to support large numbers of items, by reusing one item and setting its properties only when it needs to draw or tap a view.

How do I do this?  Can I just call the views' drawRect from within the carousel's drawRect, or do I need to do something more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

DTGridView looks nice, also consider iCarousel for iOS which will also do coverflow style

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at `PhotoScroller` sample code from Apple. Its every efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will be as simple as that since the actual drawing in `drawRect` might happen at a different time than the setup of the cell. Everything in `drawRect` should ideally just be responsible to actually draw things in that view, not the layout.

Hence UITableView has a whole bunch of methods to setup the sections, rows, etc.

You might want to have a look at Daniel Tull's [DTGridView](https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView) which is basically doing exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Slight correction: `drawRect:` draws content into the backing `CALayer`, not the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `drawRect:` You'll want to call `-[UIView setNeedsDisplay]` to invoke `-[UIView drawRect:]`. This will set up the graphics context for you to draw into.

As for the layout, your carousel should implement `-[UIView layoutSubviews]`, which you invoke by calling `-[UIView setNeedsLayout]`.